# Javascript Link to AspCore Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to pass a Javascript created string as route data in aspcore. The string is created as follows from a Javascript array:

```
<body>
    FULL LIST: <span id="Inventory"></span>
</body>    
<script>
var FullString = LargeList.concat(SmallList);
    LenB = BoxList.length;
    FullString.push(LenB);

    document.getElementById("Inventory").innerHTML = FullString.join("/");
</script>
```

I was thinking I could use Javascript again to create the link, but this doesn't seem like the right idea.

```
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="AddToFiv()" value="Create A 5/I Remark" />
    <p id="FivRemarkLink"></p>
</body>
<script>
    function AddToFiv() {

    var FullString = LargeList.concat(SmallList);
    LenB = BoxList.length;
    FullString.push(LenB);

    var Inventory = FullString.join("/");

    var text = "<a asp-action="FivCreate" asp-route-zero="@ViewBag.zero" asp-route-code="I" asp-route-priority="5" asp-route-remark=" + Inventory + ">ADD 5/I</a>";

    document.getElementById("FivRemarkLink").value = text;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,asp-xxx cannot be recognized in js,so you can use `href`,and then if you want to add  `<a></a>` to `<p id="FivRemarkLink"></p>`,you can use like this `document.getElementById("FivRemarkLink").innerHTML = text;`.

Here is a demo with fake data(`ViewBag.zero="zero"`):

```
<input type="button" onclick="AddToFiv()" value="Create A 5/I Remark" />
<p id="FivRemarkLink"></p>
<script>

    //$(function () {

    //    const LargeList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    //    const SmallList = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
    //    const BoxList = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
    //    var FullString = LargeList.concat(SmallList);
    //    LenB = BoxList.length;
    //    FullString.push(LenB);

    //    document.getElementById("Inventory").innerHTML = FullString.join("/");
    //})
     function AddToFiv() {
         const LargeList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
         const SmallList = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
         const BoxList = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
    var FullString = LargeList.concat(SmallList);
    LenB = BoxList.length;
    FullString.push(LenB);

    var Inventory = FullString.join("/");
         var text = "<a href='FivCreate?zero=@ViewBag.zero&code=I&priority=5&remark="+Inventory+"'>ADD 5/I</a>";
         document.getElementById("FivRemarkLink").innerHTML = text;
     }
    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: ok but that doesn't seem to call the action. unless I'm missing something. I need the link to call the action and carry the string through to the action and the new page.

Comment: Yes，I click the link "Add5/I",it will call the action,can you share more about your code,such as your action.so that I can try to find why you cannot go to the action.